Existence of a $N > 2024 $ such that $\forall n >N \implies \phi (n) > \phi (N)$
Does there exist $N >2024 $ such that $\phi (n) > \phi (N)  , \space \forall n>N$ ? Here $n , N \in \mathbb{N} $ and $\phi$ is the Euler's Totient Function.
I think such a $N$ doesn't exist due to the non-monotonicity of $\phi (n)$.
But if it is false , I have to produce a function $f(N):=n$ such that $\phi (n) \le \phi (N)$ for whatever $N >2024$
I thought to use prime factorisation of $N$ and $2024$ but it wasn't successful.
Thinking on the side of the answer being true , I thought to use $\phi (n)\ge \sqrt {n}$ for $n\ne 2,6$ but in vain.
Hints Please.

What is the source of this problem?  Problems referencing the current year frequently appear in contests and such.

Hint: Bound $n  \prod \frac{p-1}{p}$. $\quad$ Good candidates look like $ \prod p_i$.

Phd Entrance Exam of Indian Statistical Institute

Is this an ongoing exam?

Note that, unless you miswrote the question, you aren't asked to find such an $N$ even if one (or more) exist.  That makes it a whole lot easier.

@lulu No. It's already done .

So then ask yourself:  For a fixed $m\in \mathbb N$, can there be infinitely many solutions to $\varphi(n)=m$?

@lulu I don't think so $\phi (n)=m$ for infinitely many $n$ .Though I am not sure of the proof.

Well, start there.  The proof is not difficult.  Indeed, try to prove something seemingly stronger:  there are only finitely many $n$ for which $\varphi(n)≤m$.  Can you see how to apply that to your problem?

@lulu Ok so if $N$ is the maximum value of $n$ such that $\phi ( n)=m$ .Then $\forall n>N$ we must have $\phi(n) \ne m$ . Then sir ?

@CalvinLin  can you elaborate a bit more sir ?

That's true, but it's more useful to  say"if $N$ is the maximum $n$ such that $\varphi(n)≤m$ then $\forall n>N$ we must have $\varphi(n)>m$".  As another hint:  pretty sure the comment from @CalvinLin  points you to the least $N$ which works.

Lulu's hint is a good start. Given that you're preparing for a PhD exam, I'd strongly encourage you to think about the implications of the hints and what guidance they provide, instead of just immediately demanding more next steps.

@WillJagy  Indeed (this was also the content of CalvinLin's comment to the OP, though the link is far more detailed, of course).

Let $m\ge 2025$ . For each $ 1\le i \le m$ , let $k_i=\max { n | \phi (n) = i } $ which exist by bounded inverse solutions of $\phi $. Now let $N=\max { k_i | 1 \le  i \le m} $ . Thus for $1\le n \le N$ , we have $ \phi (n) \le m$ which gives $\forall n>N \implies \phi (n)> m> \phi (m)$ .But this $m>N $  is not necessarily true. I am stuck at this . @lulu

@CalvinLin  The $N$ is dependent on the $m>2024$ I choose in above comment .So how can I minimise or give an upper bound as suggested by you so that $m>N$

You already mentioned a bound of the form $\varphi(n)≥\sqrt {\frac n2}$.... (See, e.g., this question for a proof).

Oh, you wanted $\varphi(n)≥\sqrt n$.  For that one, see this question   It really doesn't matter which one you take, either one gets the job done.
